# How to Check JFrame Existense

Tags: java, jframe

I want to create a jbutton with function to call a jframe, but the jbutton must be able to stop calling the jframe if it was already been called and exist. How can we do that?

```
    JButtonCallJFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //step 1 - check if jframe already open/called or not

        //step 1.a - if true ignore, jbutton do nothing

        //step 1.2 - else if false,jbutton called for jframe

        ClassWithJFrame cwjFrame = new ClassWithJFrame()
        if(cwjFrame is exist){

          //DO NOTHING
        }
        else if(cwjFrame not exist){

         cwjFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`jframe.isVisible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

```
cwjFrame.isVisible() will return true if frame is already visible
```

.

```
if(cwjFrame.isVisible()){

      //DO NOTHING
 }
else if(!cwjFrame.isVisible()){

     cwjFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```